# Rails: git push heroku error: sqlite3 on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, heroku, sqlite, rubygems

I am new to the rails and I am trying to push an app to heroku (just some basic stuff for practice) I have looked at the some of the solution to sqlite3 error problem on stackoverflow and I have followed them but nothing has worked for me so far. I get the following error when I issue **git push heroku master** from the Windows command line:

```
   **Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native ex
```

tension.
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (
the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed *****

```
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
          An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot co
```

ntinue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.

!
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

My gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#gem 'sqlite3'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Comment: after adding the gem, did you run `bundle install`? Did you do `git add` for the gemfile and commit your changes properly?

Comment: bingo! That fixed the problem Abhir. git add  Gemgfile was the issue. Thanks a lot, Prakash for editing the code!

Answer (score 0):

next time you build a new app to get rid of all the fuss you must do the following: `rails new -d postgresql` ,if u don't have heroku addons installed do this `heroku addons:add heroku_postgresql:hobby-dev` ,next `heroku addons | grep POSTGRES` and finally `heroku run rake db:migrate` ,that should be it.